# How to Create unit test cases from Dll in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

In previous versions of VS, we were having **Create Unit test Wizard** option, which actually uses the **dll** and create basic test methods for each classes.

But that option is not available in VS 2013.
So is there any template which i need to download to get that option back into the **VS2013**.

Answer (score 0):

1)I think this vs2013 extension can help you:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7

Or:

2) If you have resharper , it is built in function there too.

Or:

3) Another option is to solve the issue using this workaround:
http://dl.my/2013/create-unit-tests-function-not-available-or-disabled/

Let me know if it helps you... if not, I'll try to support with a different answer.